# problem with whatsapp apps in developers facebook

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am currently developing WhatsApp chatbots using the Meta API, and I have integrated two phone numbers into my account. Each bot (App 1 with Number 1 and App 2 with Number 2) is assigned a specific number. However, I am encountering an issue where, regardless of which of the two numbers I reach out to, only App 1 responds. I would appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this matter.

try to delete app 2 and create it again, swap app numbers and nothing

Answer (score 0):

As I see there is no way to split phone numbers (or whatsapp accounts) between apps. Hopefully Meta devs would fix that soon because the only solution to have multiple bots on their platform is to register new and new companies (which isn't allowed) just to provide simultaneous work for several WhatsApp bots.